# Laravel Repository caching and pagination

Tags: php, caching, pagination, laravel-4

I have created a base repository and am now extending it to add caching, but the problem I seem to be experiencing more than most is `pagination`

in my `all()` method, I do the following without caching:

```
public function all($pagination = 20)
{
    try
    {
        $query = $this->model->newQuery();
        return $this->handlePagination($query, $pagination);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        throw $e;
    }
}

protected function handlePagination($query, $pagination)
{
    if (is_null($pagination))
    {
        return $query;
    }
    $collection = $query->paginate($pagination);
    return $collection;
}
```

This is working well, but when I try to implement caching, I want to cache each model individually and store the keys for each collection, so, if I was paginating all of the entries, I would store each paginated collection in a cache:

```
cache set.1 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
cache set.2 [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40]
```

etc...

the problem is that is seems impossible to use the actual pagination class to return the results since you are paginating only the `id`

I could return the data and the paginator separately but that seems very hacky.

Is there a way to repopulate the `Paginator` class with model data without over-writing the whole thing?

EDIT

I was thinking about something like this:

```
public function all($pagination = 20)
{
    try
    {
        $cache_key = $this->cache_key . '.all';
        $ids = Cache::get($cache_key);
        if (! $ids)
        {
            $query = $this->model->newQuery();
            $ids = $query->pluck('id');
            Cache::put($cache_key, $ids, $this->cache_ttl);
        }

        $ids = $this->handlePagination($ids, $pagination);
        $collection = new Collection();
        foreach ($ids as $id)
        {
            if ($model = $this->find($id))
            {
                $collection->put($id, $model);
            }
        }
        return $collection;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        throw $e;
    }
}

/**
 * @var \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator
 */
protected $paginator;
public function handlePagination($array, $pagination = 20)
{
    if (!is_null($pagination))
    {
        $this->paginator = Paginator::make($array, count($array), $pagination);
        return $this->paginator->getItems();
    }
    return $array;
}

public function getPaginator()
{
    return $this->paginator;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to implement caching in a project where I work and I faced a similar issue but not with pagination. But the approach should be the same.

Laravel handles internally by default query caching if the model is told to do so.

What I did was creating a class that all the objects I want to cache should extend somehow. Then you can use pagination without even thinking about caching.

In the code below, pay special attention to the following method overrides:

- newQuery
- newBaseQueryBuilder
- newFromBuilder

The CacheModel class looks like this:

```
<?php

class CacheModel extends Eloquent
{
 /**
 * Holds the query builder from which this model was fetched from.
 *
 * @var Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
 */
 protected $queryBuilder;


 /**
 * Overrides Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model's newQuery().
 * We need to do this to store the query builder in our class for caching purpuses.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
 public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
 {
    $eloquentBuilder = parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted);
    return $eloquentBuilder->rememberForever();
 }


 /**
 * Overrides Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model's newBaseQueryBuilder().
 * We need to do this to store the query builder in our class for caching purpuses.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
 */
 protected function newBaseQueryBuilder()
 {
    $queryBuilder = parent::newBaseQueryBuilder();
    $this->queryBuilder = $queryBuilder;
    return $queryBuilder;
 }


 /**
 * Overrides Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model's newFromBuilder().
 * We need to do this to update the cache.
 *
 * @return an instance of the specified resource
 */
 public function newFromBuilder($attributes = array())
 { 
    $object = parent::newFromBuilder($attributes);

    $that = $this; 

    $referencedCacheKeysFromObject = Cache::rememberForever($object->getCacheIdKey(), function() use ($that){
          return array( $that->getQueryBuilder()->getCacheKey() => true );
    });
    if ( !isset($referencedCacheKeysFromObject[$this->getQueryBuilder()->getCacheKey()] ))
    {
         # Update the cache entries that hold the object
        $referencedCacheKeysFromObject[$this->getQueryBuilder()->getCacheKey()] = true;
        Cache::forget($object->getCacheIdKey());
        Cache::forever($object->getCacheIdKey(), $referencedCacheKeysFromObject);
    }

    $referencedCacheKeysFromObjectTable = Cache::rememberForever($object->getCacheTableKey(), function() use ($that){
          return array( $that->getQueryBuilder()->getCacheKey() => true );
    });
    if ( !isset( $referencedCacheKeysFromObjectTable[$this->getQueryBuilder()->getCacheKey()] ))
    {
        # Udate the cache entries that hold objects from the object's table.
        $referencedCacheKeysFromObjectTable[$this->getQueryBuilder()->getCacheKey()] = true;
        Cache::forget($object->getCacheTableKey());
        Cache::forever($object->getCacheTableKey(), $referencedCacheKeysFromObjectTable);
    }

    return $object;
 }


 /**
 * Overrides Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model's save().
 * We need to do this to clean up the cache entries related to this object.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
 */
 public function save(array $attributes = array())
 {
    if (!$this->exists)
    {
        # If the object doesn't exists, it means that the object is gonna be created. So refresh all queries involving the object table.
        # This is needed because the new created object might fell within one of the cache entries holding references to objects of this type.
        $this->cleanUpCacheQueriesOfObjectTable();
    }
    $this->cleanUpCacheQueriesOfObject();
    return parent::save();
 }


 /**
 * Overrides Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model's delete().
 * We need to do this to clean up the cache entries related to this object.
 *
 */
 public function delete()
 {
    $this->cleanUpCacheQueriesOfObject();
    return parent::delete();
 }


 /**
 * Overrides Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model's delete().
 * We need to do this to clean up the cache entries related to this object.
 *
 */
 public static function destroy($id)
 {
    $this->find($id)->cleanUpCacheQueriesOfObject();
    Cache::forget($this->getCacheIdKey($id));
    return parent::destroy($id);
 }


 /**
 * Returns the asociated query builder from which the model was created
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
 */
 public function getQueryBuilder()
 {
    return $this->queryBuilder;
 }


 /**
 * Cleans up all the cache queries that involve this object, if any.
 *
 */
 private function cleanUpCacheQueriesOfObject()
 {
    # Clean up the cache entries referencing the object as we need to re-fetch them.
    if ( $referencedCacheKeys = Cache::get($this->getCacheIdKey()) )
    {
        foreach ($referencedCacheKeys as $cacheKey => $dummy)
        {
            Cache::forget($cacheKey);
        }
    }
 }


 /**
 * Cleans up all the cache queries that involve this object table, if any.
 * Needed when a a new object of this type is created. 
 * The cache needs to be refreshed just in case the object fells into 
 * one of the cache queries holding entries from the same type of the object.
 *
 */
 private function cleanUpCacheQueriesOfObjectTable()
 {
    # Clean up the cache entries referencing the object TABLE as we need to re-fetch them.
    if ( $referencedCacheKeys = Cache::get($this->getCacheTableKey()) )
    {          
        foreach ($referencedCacheKeys as $cacheKey => $dummy)
        {
            Cache::forget($cacheKey);
        }
    }
 }


 /**
 * Returns a string containing a key for the table cache
 *
 */
 private function getCacheTableKey()
 {
    return '_' . $this->getTable();
 }


 /**
 * Returns a string containing a key for the object cache
 *
 */
 private function getCacheIdKey($id = null)
 {
    if (!isset($id))
    {
      if (isset($this->id))
        $id = $this->id;
      else
        $id = md5(serialize($this->getAttributes()));
    }

    return $this->getCacheTableKey() . '_' . $id;
 }

}
```

Then you can do another class extending this CacheModel that could be called PaginateModel and you can do whatever pagination operations you'd like to do.
Of course the rest of the objects should extend this PaginateModel class.

EDIT: Added some if conditions in the method newFromBuilder as I just figuered out that there's a bug in APC since 3.1.3.

Comment: Very interesting class - does it fully utilize all the functions given by Eloquent and successfully cache everything?

Comment: So far we are testing out the class. So far we didn't find major issues. But you can give it a try and see if it works. The idea behind is to cache an object and all the related queries that will fetch that object. As soon as the object gets updated we invalidate all these references so the cache get's refreshed everywhere.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to embed caching into Eloquent models. Questioner was using repository design pattern so the right way to handle caching would be a cache decorator class for the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the page number along as well for caching. Sonething like this

```html
$currentPg = Input::get('page') ? Input::get('page') : '1';
$boards = Cache::remember('boards'.$currentPg, 60, function(){ return WhatEverModel::paginate(15); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create the paginator manually as instructed in [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator). So basically you need to return paginator objects from your repository and those can be cached easily. Other option is to generate the paginator on the fly based on the cached/queried parameters.